# Using the each function in jQuery to apply a class

Tags: jquery

I am using a simple each function to add a class to a set of li tags in an unordered list.

```
$('div ul li').each(function(e){
   $(this).addClass('c' + e);       
});
```

Which returns the following HTML

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="c0"></li>
        <li class="c1"></li>
        <li class="c2"></li>
        <li class="c3"></li>
    </ul>
</div>  
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="c4"></li>
        <li class="c5"></li>
        <li class="c6"></li>
        <li class="c7"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It's doing what it should which is adding the index to the end of the classname.  How can I make it so that it resets for each new unordered list. So it would return something like this.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="c0"></li>
        <li class="c1"></li>
        <li class="c2"></li>
        <li class="c3"></li>
    </ul>
</div>  
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="c0"></li>
        <li class="c1"></li>
        <li class="c2"></li>
        <li class="c3"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the JS fiddle of the code I have pasted above, with a working version of what I currently  have:  http://jsfiddle.net/kdGgK/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kdGgK/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could nest each() functions.

```
$('div ul').each(function() {
   $(this).children('li').each(function(e){
      $(this).addClass('c' + e);        
   });
});
```

Comment: I'm going to go with this one because I like the fact that it will hold true if I were to nest another UL inside of my HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/), it tells you each element index relative to its siblings

```
$('div ul li').each(function(e){
   $(this).addClass('c' + $(this).index());        
});
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/kdGgK/3/

Comment: I like the simplicity of this.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just select the `ul` first, loop through as of the `ul` and apply the class to the `li` in each of the `ul`.

```
$('div ul').each(function(e){
    $(this).find('li').each(function (e) {
        $(this).addClass('c' + e);        
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kdGgK/2/

Answer (score 1):

Apply distinct classes for each unordered list li

```
 $('div ul').each(function(){
    $(this).children('li').each( function(e){
       $(this).addClass('c' + e);       
     });
  });
```

Apply one class for each unordered list li

```
 $('div ul').each(function(e){
    $(this).children('li').addClass('c' + e);       
  });
```

Comment: This Doesn't work.  I wonder who voted this up, because it simply does not do what the OP wants.. at all.

Comment: Well it does "work" but youre right, i misread the request, iteration thru the ul foreach li, updating my answer